# spring-boot-test spyBean annotation not injecting dependency

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a spring boot application which I have recently upgraded from v1.3.3.RELEASE to v1.4.2.RELEASE.

For my integration tests in v1.3.3, I have a bean which I was able to successfully spy. I was running my tests with the profile `test` and below `passwordEncoder` was activated instead of the application's.

```
@Bean
@Profile({"test"})
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new     BCryptPasswordEncoder(ApplicationConstants.CRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS);
    final String pwdHash = "$$CONST_HASH$$";        
    PasswordEncoder peSpy = spy(passwordEncoder);
    Mockito.when(peSpy.encode("TEST_USER_CRED")).thenReturn(pwdHash);
    return peSpy;
}
```

I am doing a upgrade to v1.4.2.RELEASE and would like to use the spyBean annotation to mock a single method and not depend on profiles.

I have made following changes to my test method to try it out -

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DbUnitConfiguration(dataSetLoader = ReplacementDataSetLoader.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class,webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MockTests {

    @SpyBean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
        final String pwdHash = "$$CONST_HASH$$";
        Mockito.when(peSpy.encode("TEST_USER_CRED")).thenReturn(pwdHash);
    }
}
```

However, when I try the above, I get NPE at `Mockito.when` statement. Is there anything I am missing?

I tried to use MockBean instead of SpyBean but still has no change. I also tried to move the spy statements to `@Test` methods instead of `@Before` and still have same NPE.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was with the `TestExecutionListeners` annotation. Adding `MockitoTestExecutionListener` in addition to existing listeners fixed the injection of mock/spy beans.